# I don`t know what None means in django user

Tags: python, django

```
class MemberStaffManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, staff_id, company, position, name, password=None):
        user = self.model(
            staff_id=staff_id,
            company=company,
            name=name,
            position=position,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

I'm studying Django custom user but I don't know what `password=None` means.

Maybe not `password=null`, because `user.set_password(password)` is the code that sends `password-value`.

Please help me.

Comment: `password=None` is a keyword argument of the `create_user` method. `None` is the default value for `password` if `password` is not explicitly provided.

Comment: None is `null` or `nil` for python. So it's empty passed parameter.

Comment: When you don't want to always pass a value to function by variable or it has some predefined fixed value then you use this `password=None` statement.

Comment: thanks. all of you big help!

Answer (score 2):

This is nothing to do with django; it's a core Python feature.  It's called a "default argument".

Consider the following code:

```
def f(x=3):
    print(x)

f()  # prints "3"
f(4)  # prints "4"
```

As you can see, the value after the `=` is used if no value was provided.  This is very useful for defining functions that have a default behaviour which can be customised with different arguments.

In the django use case you've provided, they're simply allowing you to not define a password when creating a user.